# Which practice is better (Calling a method from another method multiple times or do the same thing itself)

Tags: java, performance, methods, iterator

I have these two methods in my class. The second method does the same thing but for multiple values in tens of thousands (say fifty thousands). So which one is better to go with:
**Edit**

```
public static int isUsed(int num) {
    if((port < startPort || port > endPort)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.close();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return true;
    }
}

public static int areAllUsed(int arr[]) {
    //do the same thing several thousand times     >>> Is thisbetters  OR
    // call isUsed several thousand times          >>> this is better
}
```

With better I mean the memmory or performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to reuse a piece of logic in multiple places, defining a function is the best way of reusing the code. Copy-pasting the same logic in another place is not a good idea, because it reduces readability and becomes a maintenance liability in case you must change the logic.

There is little or no performance implications because Java compiler automatically inlines static methods if it finds it beneficial.

Comment: I just forgot to mention for each test in the methods they may have to create new Objects.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav That's OK - no matter what they need to do in the tests, your other method would have to do it as well, right?

Comment: Then show us the real `isUsed()` method, instead of a fake one. You might be able to factor out the algorithm without creating the same object agian and again, but it all depends on the real code.

Comment: There is no way to reuse the same ServerSocket instance and change its port. So you're forced to create a new ServerSocket for each port. So just call `isUsed()` in a loop from `areAllUsed()`.

Answer (score 2):

DRY is the answer: Don't Repeat Yourself.

If you have the algorithm already coded in `isUsed()`, then don't reimplement it in another method. Call `isUsed()`.

The JVM is efficient enough to make the difference negligible, or even non-existent, because the `isUsed()` method will be dynamically inlined into `areAllUsed()` by the JIT.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is a good chance that the method call makes no difference from a performance perspective.  For a method that small, there is a good chance that the JIT compiler will inline the method body at the point it is called.  (And note that it can do the same thing for non-static final methods, and even non-static, non-final methods in some circumstances.)

The difference in memory usage is trivial.

---

Either way, it is a generally a bad idea to try to second-guess the compiler / optimizer.  It is better to write the code to be *readable* and *maintainable* and let the optimizer deal with optimization.  If performance is a real concern, then *profile* your finished code using real / realistic input data ... and use the results of your profiling to determine where you should be directing your effort.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application. I will suggest call isUsed several times. The less linear your code is, the easier it is to debugg if there is a problem. If there is a problem, you just need to check isUsed for error.